# How to diagnose the cause of occasional mouse micro-freezes?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

For a few months now, I've been observing occasional mouse "micro-freezes" (or "micro-stutters") where the mouse cursor stops moving for about 1 second, maybe slightly less. Today the problem has been getting worse with a micro-freeze about every 10 minutes.

When it's not stuttering, the mouse works perfectly fine and mouse cursor movements are smooth.

**What tools should I use to diagnose this issue?** I'm a native software developer and "power user" with access to many tools (Process Explorer, Process Monitor, Performance Monitor, WinDbg...) but since the freezes are occasional and relatively infrequent, I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

**What it's not**:

- Outdated Windows 10 installation (fully up-to-date Windows 1903)
- Outdated BIOS
- Any kind of heavy CPU load (happens even when the machine is idle)
- Antivirus (none running apart from whatever is built into Windows)
- Backblaze cloud backup client (turned it off entirely)
- YouTube video playing in the background

My mouse is a Logitech G Pro connected via USB, standard USB mouse driver. It has been working fine for a long time, well before the stutters appeared.

Hopefully relevant hardware specs, let me know if I should add anything:

```
OS Name:                                                Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version:                                                10.0.18362 Build 18362
System Manufacturer:                                    MSI
System Model:                                           MS-7885
Processor:                                              Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 2901 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date:                                      American Megatrends Inc. 1.E0, 6/15/2018
SMBIOS Version:                                         3.0
Embedded Controller Version:                            255.255
BIOS Mode:                                              Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer:                                 MSI
BaseBoard Product:                                      X99S SLI PLUS (MS-7885)
BaseBoard Version:                                      1.0
Platform Role:                                          Desktop
Secure Boot State:                                      Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration:                                     Binding Not Possible
Hardware Abstraction Layer:                             Version = "10.0.18362.387"
Installed Physical Memory (RAM):                        64.0 GB
Total Physical Memory:                                  63.9 GB
Available Physical Memory:                              49.1 GB
Total Virtual Memory:                                   79.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory:                               60.7 GB
Page File Space:                                        16.0 GB
Kernel DMA Protection:                                  Off
Virtualization-based security:                          Not enabled
Device Encryption Support:                              Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions:                   Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions:  Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware:           Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection:                    Yes
Drive 1:                                                Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
Drive 2:                                                Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB
Drive 3:                                                Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB
Drive 4:                                                WDC WD4003FZEX-00Z4SA0 4TB
Network Interface:                                      Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
Network Interface Driver:                               12.17.10.8
```

**Edit:** I suspect that something is wonky with the USB hardware on my motherboard (MSI X99S SLI PLUS). I've started to notice other weird behaviors like the keyboard occasionally getting stuck at boot on Windows' login page.

Comment: how is the mouse connected? usb? bluetooth? wireless dongle?

Comment: The mouse is connected via USB.

Comment: To discard hardware fault, boot using a live linux (eg, Linux Mint) and test the mouse. If it works fine then it is not a hardware problem. If it still freezeing then it is definetly a hardware problem. If it is not freezeing the issue is on Windows/drivers

Answer (score 1):

This is most often caused by a driver, so updating drivers can solve the problem.
The display driver is the most likely.

Sources for driver updates:

- Install the latest display driver. Download it only from the manufacturer
  of the display card.
- Download, install and run the
  [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html),
  to find driver updates for all your Intel devices.
- Check the computer manufacturer's support website for driver updates,
  especially the chipset driver,
  and also for a BIOS update (to be installed with utmost caution).

Comment: My system is fully up to date (BIOS, Windows, NVIDIA driver). I'm currently running NVIDIA driver 441.20 (which is the latest public version) on a GeForce RTX 2080 Ti. I've noticed the issue with multiple versions of the NVIDIA driver (I update it often).

Comment: You might instead try a version dating from before the problem started.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't choose the "poke into a specific problem" strategy but try to reduce possible causes. Starting with trying the mouse on a different computer and trying a different simpler mouse (just a standard USB-Mouse that works with the standard driver, no features) on your computer.

Comment: It's clearly not the mouse, it's been working fine for years (it's a Logitech G Pro, which is a fairly high end gaming mouse).

Comment: Let me add that I haven't installed the Logitech-specific mouse driver, I'm using the standard USB mouse driver that ships with Windows by default.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune That's a strong indication yes, but only because it worked in the past doesn't mean it's ok now. Over time every single peace of HW has a [failure rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate) of 100% (basic IT security 101). I would still put it to the test (both ways).

Answer (score 1):

Does your MS-7885 MSI board have an old-school PS/2 port?  I looked at some pictures and think I saw one.

Go to your local thrift store and get an ancient PS/2 mouse and try it.  You could also get a USB to PS/2 adapter.

If the problems go away, there's some issue with the USB driver, USB bus/device on bus, USB firmware, or UEFI firmware.

USB driver issues - Get latest from chipset vendor.

USB bus/device on bus - Are you using a USB 3.0 monitor or dock?  Is DisplayLink software installed?  These may cause freezes due to the nature of how they work, but updating all relevant software/drivers should be done.  Ensure you have latest Intel display and chipset drivers.  Disable USB power management in Power options.

Software that captures entire display like OBS, Teamviewer or other remote solution may cause problems.  Virus scanning software can also cause random freezes but not too sure it's common to freeze mouse pointer.

Also Hyper V being enabled can cause problems.

USB firmware - Update to latest version, if this is applicable.

UEFI firmware - Try disabling legacy USB options.  Update to latest firmware.  Check throttling or powersaving options, try disabling them.

Or you could continue to use your mouse with the PS/2 adapter.

Comment: I think you were almost right. I suspect that something is wonky with the USB _hardware_ on my motherboard (MSI X99S SLI PLUS). I've started to notice other weird behaviors like the keyboard occasionally getting stuck at boot on Windows' login page. This motherboard model always had some issues with USB: I RMA'd it twice when building this machine in early 2015 (IIRC it would hang when installing the ASMedia USB 3.0 drivers) and a friend of mine with the same motherboard had the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech do have their own [driver](https://www.logitechg.com/en-au/innovation/g-hub.html) for the mouse, it might be worth giving it a go as that may have provision for other issues.
Couple of extra things to consider:

Device Manager doesn't always flag a "conflict", which can make things a bit awkward to diagnose on this ancient rig each Windows version update. It's the **SB-Z** sound configuration where the AMD HD Audio Device and the RealTek HD audio are set to disabled. The WU and the AMD driver update turn them back on, which can make the SB-Z driver,- and hence the entire system rather unstable.

Another thing you can try is **Advanced System Settings**=>**System Properties**=>**Settings(Performance Options)**=>**Advanced(Tab)**=>**Change**(in Virtual Memory), and toggle the settings e.g. if from *System managed size* to *Custom*, key in the recommended page size at the bottom. A reboot is required. Doing this used to be more of a thing back in the day, now there seems to be a less chance of page pool corruption, which can also cause instability.